# Add exceptions to regular expression boundary

Tags: javascript

I have

```
Exemple.match(/.{1,21}\b/g).map(s => s.trim())
```

I need to include some emoji as exceptions, because i get them deleted, if i enter emoji ( ,        ☺️  )

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Maybe [here](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex) you can find some tips about this

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem,

This is how i manage to solve it,

```
exemple.match(/.{1,21}|(||||||||☺️|)\b/g.map(s => s.trim())
```

Tell me if this is working.